# Replacing Regex matches using lambda expression

Tags: c#, regex, lambda, substitution

I'm looking for a simple regex find and replace solution were I can just provide a lambda expression for replacing each matches. E.g:

```
regex.MatchReplace(text, match => "replacement string");
```

This way I can create my own logic for generating the replacement string which may involve invoking various methods etc. i.e. things you can't do with substitution patterns. Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: `Regex` already have overloads of `Replace` with `MatchEvaluator`. Why do you need your own? `regex.Replace(text, match => "replacement string");` should work for you.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how I managed to overlook that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regex already has one. For ex,

```
string input="abc123def";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d", m=>(m.Value[0]-'0'+ 5).ToString());
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

OUTPUT: abc678def

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx

You can define an extension method for the RegEx class which will allow you to specify an `Action<>` as an argument.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear but I was looking for an actual implementation of the extension method.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an example to hand. Have you made an attempt yourself? You are more likely to get an answer if you post your existing solution.

Comment: I have a solution in the works - it involves matching twice though - once to store all matches, another to go through and replace. I thought that perhaps for such a basic operation there would be performant solutions available.